# Distance Between Two Points Same Value Different Feature Classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, distance

I have two point feature classes - one is the original data and one is the data after editing. I want to know how far each of the points moved in the editing process. How do I compare all of the points in the new data to the points in the old data that have the same ID# and display the distance between them? Also I have the standard license, so I don't have access to the Near or Generate Near Table tools.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (i.e. SQL Server, Oracle, PostGIS)?

Comment: Is it likely that the original feature will be the closest to the moved feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a non scripting perspective, it would be fairly straightforward to do the following:

1. Add two fields to each feature class: X1, Y1, X2, Y2
2. Calculate Geometry to populate the fields with the coordinates
3. Join the two feature classes by common ID#
4. Add a 4th field, DIST
5. Field calculator with Python

`DIST = math.hypot(!X1!-!X2!, !Y1!-!Y2!)`

Comment: out of curiosity, how well does this solution accommodate for points that span several projections? Would the distortion be significant?

Comment: This works well for close points in say a single state plane system but not across global projections or similar.

Comment: Data in a single feature class can't be in different projections (by definition, all geometries share a single coordinate reference).

Comment: @Conor, it depends on the projections. Some projections emphasize area while others deal with distance. It would be strange if the two feature classes weren't in the same coordinate system, though...

Comment: In which measure units is the resulting distance?
I have to point out that this doesn't answer to displaying these distances as lines.

Comment: @MicheleCordini, the distance is in the units of the feature class. I you want different units, there's a handful of ways to accomplish that.